# Multiple client-server socket programming

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, serversocket

I am trying to implement socket programming using two programming languages. I want to connect multiple clients with one server and when the client types exit the server should print a message and the client closes the connection. The issue is my java client sends the text separately. when the client types "exit" for example, the server gets it as:

```
e
xit.
```

how to send them as one string? because if the server gets only "xit" it won't work correctly.

I've tried two "DataOutputStream" functions"
1: writeBytes : which separate the text
2: writeUTF : the server considers the text correctly and when the client typed "exit" the server won't execute the condition.

Also, how to make the server broadcasts the message to all connected clients?
Server code:

```
import socket
import sys
import traceback
from threading import Thread


def main():
    start_server()


def start_server():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 8888         

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)   
    print("Server started and socket created")

    try:
        s.bind((host, port))
    except:
        print("Error!!: " + str(sys.exc_info()))
        sys.exit()

    s.listen(5)       # maximum number of clients can connect to the server
    print("Server is waiting for clients")


    while True:
        connection, address = s.accept()
        ip, port = str(address[0]), str(address[1])
        print("Server receives connection from " + ip + ":" + port)
        try:
            Thread(target=client_thread, args=(connection, ip, port)).start()
        except:
            print("Thread did not start.")
            traceback.print_exc()

    s.close()


def client_thread(connection, ip, port, max_buffer_size = 5120):
    is_active = True

    while is_active:
        client_input = receive_input(connection, max_buffer_size)
        if client_input == 'exit':
            print("Client (" + port + ") want to close the connection and exit")
            connection.close()
            print("Connection " + ip + ":" + port + " closed")
            is_active = False
        else:
            print("Client (" + port +  ") said : " + format(client_input))
            connection.sendall("-".encode("utf8"))


def receive_input(connection, max_buffer_size):
    client_input = connection.recv(max_buffer_size)
    client_input_size = sys.getsizeof(client_input)

    if client_input_size > max_buffer_size:
        print("The input size is greater than expected {}".format(client_input_size))

    decoded_input = client_input.decode("utf8").rstrip()  # decode and strip end of line
    result = process_input(decoded_input)

    return result


def process_input(input_str):
    return  str(input_str)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Client code in Python to get my idea:

```
import socket
import sys

def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 8888

    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
    except:
        print("Connection error")
        sys.exit()

    print("To close the connection type (exit)")
    message = input(" Type: ")

    while True:
        s.sendall(message.encode("utf8"))
        if s.recv(5120).decode("utf8") == "-":
            pass      

        message = input(" Type: ")
        if message == 'exit':
         s.send(message.encode("utf8"))
         break;
    s.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Java code which I need help with:

```
import java.net.*;

public class ClientJava {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        String sentence;
        String localhost = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 8888;

        BufferedReader inData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(localhost, port);
        DataOutputStream outData = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());


        sentence = inData.readLine();
        outData.writeBytes(sentence);
        while (!sentence.equals("exit"))
        {sentence = inData.readLine();
        outData.writeBytes(sentence);

        }
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your clients are not equivalent. You are reading lines in Java but you are not writing lines from Python. Either add a line terminator or don't use `readLine()`.

Comment: where to use the line terminator?

Comment: Add it to the messages you are sending, or don't use `readLine()`.